# How to prove ties to my home country as a university student in a foreign country?

Tags: indian-citizens, israel, schengen-visas

I hold an Indian passport and I'm studying for a Master's in Biology in Israel (to be completed in March 2018). I plan to visit Greece and Turkey on my way from Israel to India after completion of the degree. Since I do not have any offer from any Indian universities as of now, I will have no occupation at the time of travel and I will be seen as a potential immigrant to Greece. Therefore, I need to demonstrate strong ties to home country for which I plan to submit the following:

1. My ownership of land in India.
2. Mutual fund investment.
3. My bank account statements in Israel and India (Just to demonstrate sound financial conditions that implies I do not need to seek a job/employment immediately).

Is there anything else I can use to show such ties? I can produce a letter from my Israeli university certifying my student status at the time of visa application but that will not be valid at the time of travel.

Also, do you think having used visas from USA (J1- visa), Switzerland (National Visa), Israel and Schengen visas from Spain, Italy and Austria will give me any slight advantage? I have always departed those countries well before the visa expired and hope they will pay attention to such information.

Also, I intend to travel within Turkey after my Greece itinerary by obtaining a Turkish e-visa using the Schengen visa (if approved) as a supporting document. Should I also present the Turkey itinerary to the Greek embassy just to convince them a little more about my intention to depart Greece on time?

Any response will be highly appreciated in this matter.

Comment: Do you _have_ strong ties? Apparently you've been able to get by without regular access to your land during the master's program you're finishing; and mutual funds investments and bank accounts are easy to enjoy from afar.

Comment: I want to start a PhD in India (Coz I miss my family) but have no proof of that to convince them. I do not know how to give proof of such emotional ties (they may not be of much significance). However, my foreign stays were short (2.5 years in Israel, 2 months each in USA and Switzerland, both for studies, 10 days each in three schengen tourist trips). My parents are going to retire in 2018 but they will still get pension and not dependent on me. I cannot think of anything else at this point. Please suggest if you have any other idea of 'strong ties' in mind.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51589/proving-ties-to-your-home-country-when-applying-for-a-german-visa-as-a-non-emplo

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-what-are-some-helpful-tips-for-preparing

Comment: I think your travel history should give you more than a slight advantage.