# Can I get a Schengen visa with no employment?

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork

I applied for my schengen visa stating on my cover letter that I am about to finish my contract at my current employment. I am a South African working in China. I asked for 71 days in Schengen and my bank statement shows that I have at least 3 times in my balance as what is required for that period. The visa centre said without an employment letter my case won't be as strong, and said I should add it. But surely you can't add an employment letter stating employment you won't have during your travels?? My plan is to go back to South Africa after my trip.
Now I am quite nervous. Should I send them an employment letter? Could they deny me because of that?

Comment: No, you can’t - that would be deception. You need to provide evidence of ties to show a reason why you will leave the Schengen area at the end of your trip. Typically that’s a job, family dependents etc.

Comment: Seems like you were well paid in China which implies you have professional skills. To me this means you are better off in a skilled job in south Africa than as an overstayer in Europe working in the unofficial economy, which of course would count in your favour if the visa office take the same view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving ties to your home country when applying for a Schengen visa as a non-employed visa national?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51589/proving-ties-to-your-home-country-when-applying-for-a-schengen-visa-as-a-non-emp) and [How to prove that you have significant ties with family in your home country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country)